# Добавление в автозагрузку

Tags: windows, c++

Здравствуйте, я хочу добавить свою программу в автозагрузку Windows, но никак не могу найти код для этого. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Какой язык?

Comment: язык С++!!

Comment: [Автозапуск программы при включении компютера C++](http://hashcode.ru/questions/31679/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-c).

Answer (score 1):

Автозагрузку можно осуществить, сделав определенные записи в реестр. Какие именно - можете посмотреть [здесь](http://argon.pro/windows/winxp/xpautorun). Как работать с реестром, обратитесь к соответственной литературе.

Comment: спасибо огромное